# Duplicate value in XMLAGG and RTRIM SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

The Below query brings in duplicate values

```
SELECT maxuser.userid,
       person.displayname,
       maxuser.status,
       sod_Report.severity,
       sod_Report.scenario,
       RTRIM(XMLAGG(Xmlelement(E,groupuser.groupname,',').EXTRACT('//text()')   ORDER BY groupuser.groupname).GetClobVal(),',') groupname 
FROM   maxuser
       INNER JOIN person
               ON maxuser.userid = person.personid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.groupuser
                    ON maxuser.userid = groupuser.userid
                       AND maxuser.userid = person.personid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN sod_report
                    ON sod_report.userid = maxuser.userid
                       AND sod_report.userid = person.personid
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND (( maxuser.userid LIKE '%XX%' ))
GROUP  BY maxuser.userid,
          person.displayname,
          maxuser.status,
          sod_Report.severity,
          sod_Report.scenario
```

The output is coming as below

```
USERID  DISPLAYNAME  GROUPNAME 
 XXXX    Test User   A1,A1,B1,B1,C1,C1
```

Expected output

```
USERID  DISPLAYNAME  GROUPNAME 
XXXX    Test User    A1,B1,C1
```

I have to use `RTRIM` and `XMLAGG` since the output of `GROUPNAME` should be displayed in single line separated by commas. This is for Oracle database , Please advise.

Comment: Please add **(1)** a tag of database+version **(2)** small data sample

Comment: I think `XMLAGG` is a Oracle function https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm

Comment: @Prdp, Yes it is. Still need version.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Oracle 11.2

Comment: For start, why don't you use LISTAGG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo

Add an additional step before the aggregation, that uses ROW_NUMBER.

```
create table groupuser (groupname varchar2(100));

insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('A1');
insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('A1');
insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('B1');
insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('B1');
insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('C1');
insert into groupuser (groupname) values ('C1');
```

---

```
select  listagg (case when rn=1 then groupname end,',') within group (order by groupname)

from   (select  groupname
               ,row_number () over (partition by groupname order by null) as rn

        from    groupuser
        )
;
```

---

```
select  rtrim(xmlagg(case when rn=1 then xmlelement(e,groupname,',').extract('//text()') end order by groupname).getclobval(),',')  

    from   (select  groupname
                   ,row_number () over (partition by groupname order by null) as rn

            from    groupuser
            )
    ;
```

---

```
SELECT userid,
       displayname,
       status,
       severity,
       scenario,
       RTRIM(XMLAGG(Xmlelement(E,groupname,',').EXTRACT('//text()')   ORDER BY groupname).GetClobVal(),',') groupname 


FROM (
        SELECT maxuser.userid,
               person.displayname,
               maxuser.status,
               sod_Report.severity,
               sod_Report.scenario,
               groupuser.groupname,
               row_number () over (partition by groupuser.groupname order by null) as rn

        FROM   maxuser
               INNER JOIN person
                       ON maxuser.userid = person.personid
               LEFT OUTER JOIN maximo.groupuser
                            ON maxuser.userid = groupuser.userid
                               AND maxuser.userid = person.personid
               LEFT OUTER JOIN sod_report
                            ON sod_report.userid = maxuser.userid
                               AND sod_report.userid = person.personid
        WHERE  1 = 1
               AND (( maxuser.userid LIKE '%XX%' ))
    ) t



GROUP BY userid,
       displayname,
       status,
       severity,
       scenario
;
```

Comment: the listagg works on GROUPUSER table however it doesn't when it's combined with other tables. the groupname should come up based on the userid mapped between maxuser.userid=groupuser.userid. I get an error as string concatenation is too long

Comment: I might be doing some silly mistake however can you please give me on how to map other tables like MAXUSER and SOD_REPORT in the LISTAGG query which you have mentioned . When I run the query then it brings in output however when I combine this query with other tables using joins then its does come up , Thanks much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
select rtrim(regexp_replace('A1,A1,B1,B1,C1,C1','(\w+)(,(\1))+,?','\1,'),',') from dual
```